# Null Pointer Exception in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, angularjs, eclipse

Whenever I'm clicking on any project or any jsp pages or java file in my Eclipse Luna 'Null Pointer Exception' is being thrown. This issue is occurring since I tried to install angular js plugin. I can't understand what the problem is. Please help.

[image: (please click on this link provided)---Eclipse issue that is occuring]

Comment: Can you try this. Minimize pop-up and close the file tabs that are opened and then close pop-up and restart eclipse

Comment: Actually restarting and all stopping/starting server/machine everything I did but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

I guess [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385680) bug is filed for Eclipse

You could try restarting Eclipse.
Also you can update your eclipse by clicking it on help >> check for updates, also you can start eclipse by entering command in command prompt eclipse -clean.

Comment: Actually I restarted Eclipse many times and even I restarted my machine many times for this bug only. But nothing happened. Will the 'update eclipse' impact any of my existing projects? Because there are many important projects and I can't take risk with them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the error log? You can check in window>show view>error log.There you can find out why its coming

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I just checked the error log. I could not understand the issue. It will be very helpful of you if you can say what the problem is.[please click on this link to see the error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbtEm.png)